# graph in console visual c++ real time

Tags: c++, graph, console-application, real-time

I want to make graph from the result of the sensors, I read the sensors from arduino board.
I use console application program in VC++ 2010.

But after I search in the google, it seems imposible to make graph from the console application.

Is there any library or other application to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* make graphs in a console program, but they have to be using ASCII instead of, well, graphical. Something like this:

```
Y
^
|   *
| * *
| * *
| * * *
+-------> X
  A B C
```

If you want a "proper" graphical application, you have to use another project-type when creating the project.

Unfortunately if you have the Express version of Visual Studio you can't really make a GUI application easily, you have to make a WIN32 project and handle the GUI much yourself.

Comment: Thank you, for your sugestion, may be I have to change to win32 project

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the Express version of VC++ 2010 it might be easier to create an MFC Dialog application - that will give you a simple GUI that you can use to begin creating the graph.

Comment: thank you, actualy I use VC++ 2010 ultimate, so may be I can use MFC dialog. Is there any tutorial for MFC in win32 console application, I just find that this MFC run in win32 project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really do graphics in a visual studio console application.
Your best option is port your application to Win32 or .Net

Or, if you really want to stay in console, you could go back to old school Turbo C++ and do graphic programming there. Hint: graphics.h

Comment: thank you, It sound not good if I use TC++ :), may be I have to change to use win32 rather than win32 console aplication